# How can an session remain open while modifying JSF code?

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, jsf

I'm developing an app from Eclipse Neon 64bits on JSF 2.2, which I run on web server Tomcat 8.

My problem is, that whenever I detect an error in my code and I correct it over the .java files, Tomcat restablishes the session information, so for every amendment I make, I have to log in again. I wish that, even if I make changes to my code, the app session would remain open.

Hope you can help me with this issue.

Thanks!

Comment: I am not aware of any chance to retain a session over redeployment. Depending on how you implemented your login mechanism consider adding an automated login mechanism for development with default development/test user credentials. You still do not retain the old session but have a new one and do not have to enter login credentials.

Answer (score 0):

You mean to say `hot deployment` see this [article](https://www.mkyong.com/eclipse/how-to-configure-hot-deploy-in-eclipse/)

**Hot Deployment**: Hot-deployable services are those which can be added to or removed from the running server. It is the ability to change ON-THE-FLY what’s currently deployed without redeploying it. The time savings realized when your developers can simply run their build and have the new code auto-deploy instead of build, shutdown, startup is massive.

or normally,

**Cold Deployment**:Cold deployment are defined as tasks that require one or more instances of the server to restart to reflect the changes.
Cold deployment is slow but stable:

- Stop JBoss AS
- Optionally delete data/, log/, tmp/, work/
- Redeploy your application(s)
- Start JBoss AS

There are prons and cons of both way, it is recommended to test your application again in normal mode as well.